# drag and drop (checkmark if I drag the right image) android

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop

If I drag a countryTypical image and drop in imageCountry[n9] the application set the checkmark image on the right countryTypical image. 
It happens if I drag the right countryTypical image and also if I drag the mistaken countryTypical image. I would like to correct the error.
Many thanks...

```
String[] countryNames = {
        "Italy", "France", "Spain", "Germany", "Belgium", "Portugal", "Switzerland", "Great Britain"
};

int[] countryImages = {
        R.drawable.italy,
        R.drawable.france,
        R.drawable.spain,...
};
int[] countryFlags = {
        R.drawable.italian_flag,
        R.drawable.french_flag,
        R.drawable.spanish_flag,....
};
```

In my OnCreate:

```
countryTypical1.setImageResource(countryFlags[n1]);
    countryTypical2.setImageResource(countryFlags[n2]);
    countryTypical3.setImageResource(countryFlags[n3]);
    countryTypical4.setImageResource(countryFlags[n4]);
    countryTypical5.setImageResource(countryFlags[n5]);
    countryTypical6.setImageResource(countryFlags[n6]);
    countryTypical7.setImageResource(countryFlags[n7]);
    countryTypical8.setImageResource(countryFlags[n8]);

    countryTypical1.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical2.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical3.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical4.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical5.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical6.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical7.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);
    countryTypical8.setOnTouchListener(dragClick);

    imageCountry.setOnDragListener(DropListener);
```

View.OnTouchListener dragClick = new View.OnTouchListener() {

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            DragShadow dragShadow = new DragShadow(view);

            ClipData dragData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            view.startDrag(dragData, dragShadow, view,0);
            return true;
        }
        return true;
    }
};



private class DragShadow extends View.DragShadowBuilder{

    public DragShadow(View view) {
        super(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProvideShadowMetrics(Point shadowSize, Point shadowTouchPoint) {
        View view = getView();
        int height = view.getHeight();
        int width = view.getWidth();

        shadowSize.set(width, height);
        shadowTouchPoint.set(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas) {
        getView().draw(canvas);
    }
}


View.OnDragListener DropListener = new View.OnDragListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical1, event, n1);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical2, event, n2);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical3, event, n3);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical4, event, n4);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical5, event, n5);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical6, event, n6);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical7, event, n7);
        assignDropTrue(countryTypical8, event, n8);
        return true;
    }

};



private void assignDropTrue(ImageView countryTypical, DragEvent event, int n1){
    if (n9 == n1){
        int dragEvent = event.getAction();
        switch (dragEvent) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                countryTypical.setImageResource(R.drawable.vcheckmark);
        }}
}
```

Comment: 'if (n9 == n1)', what is n9 in your case?

Comment: n9 = r.nextInt(countryFlags.length);

Comment: The problem is in the switch-case, you propably have to check in the DragEvent.ACTION_DROP case if you are droping the image with the right mapping. I can't help any further because I don't really understand all aspects of your code. (e.g what's n1-n8? integers between 0-7?)

Comment: exactly. So the images are all different.

Comment: I want that only if I drag and drop the right image, it become checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a sample just to give you an idea behind the logic I propose (a.k.a it's not tested)

```
View.OnDragListener DropListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
      @Override
      public boolean onDrag(View view, DragEvent event) {
          int action = event.getAction();
          View draggedView = (View) event.getLocalState();
          //view is the country where the flag was dropped, draggedView is the flag you dropped
          //below we check if the correct flag is dropped in the correct country

      switch (event.getAction()){
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: 
          for (int i; i< countryImages.length(); i++){
               if (draggedView.getId() == countryFlags[i] && view.getId()== countryImages[i])
                   draggedView.setImageResource(R.drawable.vcheckmark); 

          }            
          break;
        default:
          break;
        }
        return true;
      }   
    };
```